# replicate-wild-do-table=channel_name:db_name.% doesn't work in MySQL 8.0 for channel based replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-8.0, master-slave-replication, percona-server

I am trying to configure a replication topology where there will be one slave which will connect to two masters. **Percona Server 8.0.25**.

**Master1**- main master

**bkp_server** - slave to master1 and abz_master

**abz_master** - slave to master1

Master1 has 10 schema (A to J)out of these 10, seven (A to G) schema are to be replicated to **bkp_server** and the remaining three schema (H,I,J) are to be replicated to **abz_master**. From **abz_master**, then these three schema (H I J) will be replicated to **bkp_server**.

I have attached an image to show the setup. I have to add the image to make it clear what I am trying to achieve. For some reason, I have to use such a topology. I know I can directly replicate all the schema from master1 to the bkp_server but that is not the requirement and my main question is about the failure of replicate-wild-do-table filters.

```
Replication From master1 to the bkp_server  - CHANGE MASTER TO is as follows
bkp_server> CHANGE MASTER TO master_host='master1', master_user='replica', master_password='Pass@123', master_log_file='master1_binlog.000004', master_log_pos=2692 for channel "master1";

Replication From abz_master to the bkp_server - CHANGE MASTER TO is as follows
bkp_server> CHANGE MASTER TO master_host='abz_master', master_user='replica', master_password='Pass@123', master_log_file='abz_master_binlog.000005', master_log_pos=6684 for channel "abz_master";
```

On the slave bkp_server I am using following replication filters

```
replicate-wild-do-table=master1:A.%
replicate-wild-do-table=master1:B.%
replicate-wild-do-table=master1:C.%
replicate-wild-do-table=master1:D.%
replicate-wild-do-table=master1:E.%
replicate-wild-do-table=master1:F.%
replicate-wild-do-table=master1:G.%
replicate-wild-do-table=abz_master:H.%
replicate-wild-do-table=abz_master:I.%
replicate-wild-do-table=abz_master:J.%
```

but these filters replicate-wild-do-table seem to do nothing. I have gone through this
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-rules-channel-based-filters.html
where it mentions the following about replicate-wild-do-table
**--replicate-wild-do-table=channel:table regexid**.

It doesn't provide the options like --replicate-wild-do-table=channel:db_name.table% but if I read the description for --replicate-wild-do-table on the link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-replica.html#option_mysqld_replicate-wild-do-table

it certainly provides for that syntax.

> This option supports channel specific replication filters, enabling multi-source replicas to use specific filters for different sources. To configure a channel specific replication filter on a channel named channel_1 use **--replicate-wild-do-table:channel_1:db_name.tbl_name**. In this case, the first colon is interpreted as a separator and subsequent colons are literal colons. See Section 17.2.5.4, “Replication Channel Based Filters” for more information.

Could you help me understand what I am missing.
I am able to start replication using replicate-ignore-db and replicate-do-db. The slave shows channel based replication filters for replicate-ignore-db and replicate-do-db but it doesn't show correct replication filters for replicate-wild-do-table.

For --replicate-ignore-db it shows only the names of the schema to be ignored in the SHOW SLAVE STATUS output, but for --replicate-wild-do-table, it shows the entire rule mentioned in the config file like master1:A.%,master1:B.%,master1:C% and so on.

Please help me understand what I am missing.[image]

Comment: I think I got I am using replicate-wild-do-table= instead I ought to use replicate-wild-do-table: — am I correct, I will try this on Monday though.

Comment: That is a _very_ non-standard replication topology.  bkp receives the _same_ data from master1 via two routes.  Do you prevent this duplication?  Are you using GTIDs?

Comment: "but that is not the requirement" -- Please justify the "requirement", else we will spend our time explaining why it is s.....

Comment: Are there any _other_ `replicate_...` or `binlog_...` lines in the configuration on any of the 3 servers?

Comment: Thanks for response Mr James. I am sorry I didn’t mention all the details. The setup is bigger than what I showed in the image actually. I personally don’t like this setup, but, once the migration of the 3 schema from master1 to abz_master is done, the three schema will be dropped from master1 and some applications will connect to abz_master instead of master1.

Comment: There are no other —replicate or —binlog options anywhere in the entire topology. This is an old setup and we are still using traditional binlog replication. I have recommended GTIDs but it will take some time. There won’t be any duplicates. It was decided to separate the big schema from master1 and put them on abz_master and because all the applications connected to master1, after this migration, some applications will connect to abz_master, thus reducing some load from master1

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for channel replication is

```
replicate-wild-do-table=channel_name:db_name.%
```

I was able to use the `replicate-wild-do-table` options in channel replication.